# Stalled event is triggered on MPEGDash playback event video is playing. Any references?

Tags: mpeg-dash, mpd, dash.js

I have written a program which downloads the next segment depending on the "timeupdateevent"

But sometimes when I am loading timeupdate event is not triggered and stalled event is triggered.. which is stopping my segment download.

Any suggestions/references to findout the issue causing the problem?